# Fatal error when running make: 'ext/stdio_filebuf.h' file not found

Tags: unix

When compiling source code with the "make" command the following error message came up

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in src
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -g -O2 -MT alignment.o -MD -MP -MF 
.deps/alignment.Tpo -c -o alignment.o alignment.cpp
mv -f .deps/alignment.Tpo .deps/alignment.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..     -g -O2 -MT fasta.o -MD -MP -MF 
.deps/fasta.Tpo -c -o fasta.o fasta.cpp
In file included from fasta.cpp:1:
./fasta.h:8:10: fatal error: 'ext/stdio_filebuf.h' file not found
#include <ext/stdio_filebuf.h>
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [fasta.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: GIve us the source code that you are compiling. Or project that you are working on.

Comment: and what OS are you using?